# Pillow ~= 9.2 not found when installing package dependancy

Tags: python, pip, python-imaging-library, pypi, setup.py

Im working on a custom pygame package that adds some more functions and features to pygame so that I don't need to repeat a lot of code. Here is the [source code](https://github.com/KidCoderT/my_first_package) of the package and [this](https://test.pypi.org/project/kct-pygame-tools/) is where I host the package on test.pypi

My problem with the code is that locally when I install with `pip install -e .` it works perfectly but the second ii create the build versions and upload with twine, if I try `pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ kct-pygame-tools==5.2.2` this is what comes:

```
C:\Users\**\my_first_package>venv\Scripts\activate

(venv) C:\Users\**\my_first_package>pip freeze

(venv) C:\Users\**\my_first_package>pip install setuptools wheel
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\tejas.desktop-ofrcmeb\devstuff\books\python-for-geeks\chapter 2\my_first_package\venv\lib\site-packages (58.1.0)
Collecting wheel
  Using cached wheel-0.37.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
Installing collected packages: wheel
Successfully installed wheel-0.37.1

(venv) C:\Users\**\my_first_package>pip install twine    
Collecting twine
  Using cached twine-4.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
Collecting requests-toolbelt!=0.9.0,>=0.8.0
  Using cached requests_toolbelt-0.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (54 kB)
Collecting urllib3>=1.26.0
  Using cached urllib3-1.26.12-py2.py3-none-any.whl (140 kB)
Collecting rich>=12.0.0
  Using cached rich-12.5.1-py3-none-any.whl (235 kB)
Collecting importlib-metadata>=3.6
  Using cached importlib_metadata-4.12.0-py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
Collecting rfc3986>=1.4.0
  Using cached rfc3986-2.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (31 kB)
Collecting requests>=2.20
  Using cached requests-2.28.1-py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
Collecting keyring>=15.1
  Using cached keyring-23.9.0-py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
Collecting pkginfo>=1.8.1
  Using cached pkginfo-1.8.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
Collecting readme-renderer>=35.0
  Using cached readme_renderer-37.0-py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
Collecting zipp>=0.5
  Using cached zipp-3.8.1-py3-none-any.whl (5.6 kB)
Collecting pywin32-ctypes!=0.1.0,!=0.1.1
  Using cached pywin32_ctypes-0.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (28 kB)
Collecting jaraco.classes
  Using cached jaraco.classes-3.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (6.0 kB)
Collecting docutils>=0.13.1
  Using cached docutils-0.19-py3-none-any.whl (570 kB)
Collecting bleach>=2.1.0
  Using cached bleach-5.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (160 kB)
Collecting Pygments>=2.5.1
  Using cached Pygments-2.13.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17
  Using cached certifi-2022.6.15-py3-none-any.whl (160 kB)
Collecting idna<4,>=2.5
  Using cached idna-3.3-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
Collecting charset-normalizer<3,>=2
  Using cached charset_normalizer-2.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
Collecting commonmark<0.10.0,>=0.9.0
  Using cached commonmark-0.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (51 kB)
Collecting webencodings
  Using cached webencodings-0.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting six>=1.9.0
  Using cached six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting more-itertools
  Using cached more_itertools-8.14.0-py3-none-any.whl (52 kB)
Installing collected packages: webencodings, pywin32-ctypes, commonmark, zipp, urllib3, six, rfc3986, Pygments, pkginfo, more-itertools, idna, docutils, charset-normalizer, certifi, rich, requests, jaraco.classes, importlib-metadata, bleach, requests-toolbelt, readme-renderer, keyring, twine
Successfully installed Pygments-2.13.0 bleach-5.0.1 certifi-2022.6.15 charset-normalizer-2.1.1 commonmark-0.9.1 docutils-0.19 idna-3.3 importlib-metadata-4.12.0 jaraco.classes-3.2.2 keyring-23.9.0 more-itertools-8.14.0 pkginfo-1.8.3 pywin32-ctypes-0.2.0 readme-renderer-37.0 requests-2.28.1 requests-toolbelt-0.9.1 rfc3986-2.0.0 rich-12.5.1 six-1.16.0 twine-4.0.1 urllib3-1.26.12 webencodings-0.5.1 zipp-3.8.1

(venv) C:\Users\**\my_first_package>pip freeze
bleach==5.0.1
certifi==2022.6.15        
charset-normalizer==2.1.1 
commonmark==0.9.1
docutils==0.19
idna==3.3
importlib-metadata==4.12.0
jaraco.classes==3.2.2     
keyring==23.9.0
more-itertools==8.14.0    
pkginfo==1.8.3
Pygments==2.13.0
pywin32-ctypes==0.2.0     
readme-renderer==37.0
requests==2.28.1
requests-toolbelt==0.9.1
rfc3986==2.0.0
rich==12.5.1
six==1.16.0
twine==4.0.1
urllib3==1.26.12
webencodings==0.5.1
zipp==3.8.1

(venv) C:\Users\**\my_first_package>pip install -i https://test.pypi.org/simple/ kct-pygame-tools==5.2.2
Looking in indexes: https://test.pypi.org/simple/
Collecting kct-pygame-tools==5.2.2
  Downloading https://test-files.pythonhosted.org/packages/10/01/8f7282bf8d204746bdf4ac1a996f0f16818e032ee2557c8b4d9818ad6861/kct_pygame_tools-5.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Pillow~=9.2 (from kct-pygame-tools) (from versions: 8.0.0.dev0)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for Pillow~=9.2

(venv) C:\Users\**\my_first_package>
```

I don't know why especially because when I do the command locally it works perfectly.

I even tried upgrading pip but that still did not work.

Please tell me what I need to do and why it's not working. I tried looking up the error but no result was found especially for my problem. Thank you

Comment: Try installing `pillow` first with `pip install pillow~=9.2`.

Comment: that is one solution but i was really hoping to know if there was a way I didn't need to do the extra step

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+test.pypi.org

Comment: `pip install --index-url https://test.pypi.org/simple/ --extra-index-url https://pypi.org/simple kct-pygame-tools==5.2.2`